# How to serve folder using location

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I would like to match a specific location URL to serve a static file on my website

Here is the two behaviors that I would like to implement :

1. (**WORKING** but an error appears on the logs) 
   **http://mywebsite.net** serves **/var/www/html/portfolio/index.html**
2. (**NOT WORKING**) **http://mywebsite.net/project** serves **/var/www/html/project/build/index.html**

Here is my actual code :

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    error_log /home/florian/nginx_www.error.log;
    root /var/www/html/portfolio;
    index index.html;

    location = /project {
        root /var/www/html/project/build;
        index index.html;
    }
}
```

Here is the actual error I get :

```
2019/01/19 20:38:47 [error] 7780#7780: *4 open() 
"/var/www/html/project/build/project" failed (2: No such file or 
directory), client: XX.XX.XX.XX, server: , request: "GET /project 
HTTP/1.1", host: "mywebsite.xx.net"
```

This behavior is actually normal because this URL doesn't give anything correct.
I would like that the URL served:

- **/var/www/html/project/build/project**
- becomes
- **/var/www/html/project/build/**

Additionnaly, I also have an issue when I reach the my website using this URL http://mywebsite.net . However the files are still being served

```
2019/01/19 20:37:46 [error] 7780#7780: *5 open() 
"/var/www/html/portfolio/undefined" failed (2: No such file or 
directory), client: XX.XX.XX.XX, server: , request: "GET /undefined 
HTTP/1.1", host: "mywebsite.xx.net", referrer: 
"http://mywebsite.xx.net/"
```

Comment: You'll need to introduce a [`rewrite` module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) in your `location` block. I could be wrong, but try `rewrite /project/(.*) /$1` which captures everything after `/project` and rewrites to `/<paths>`. When it tries fetching from `root` directory, it should find your files.

Comment: A better statement would be: `rewrite ^/project/(.*)$ /$1`

Comment: What is generating the `GET /undefined` request? Is it something inside `index.html`?

Comment: @RichardSmith definitely looks like it

Comment: The `GET/undefined` was infact a mistake related to my code, not Nginx.  I tried to add the `rewrite ^/project/(.*)$ /$1` but the URL served still looks like 
`/var/www/html/project/build/project`